# Unable to create a decision tree in R

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree

I am not able to understand the below error when I am trying to construct a decision tree. What are factor predictors? Does the number of levels of the factor predictors refer to the number of possible value that predictor can have?

```
> training_data
     SCHOOL_TYPE URBAN_RURAL NRC_CLASS
1743           G           U      FAIL
2779           U           R         1
1009           G           U      FAIL
4188           G           R      PASS
2264           A           R      PASS
6798           G           R      PASS
2734           A           R      PASS
1004           U           U         2
747            U           U      FAIL
1999           A           U         2
> tree_model = tree(NRC_CLASS~., training_data)
Error in tree(NRC_CLASS ~ ., training_data) : 
  factor predictors must have at most 32 levels
> str(training_data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SCHOOL_TYPE: Factor w/ 154 levels ""," ,01K,31E,61H,81K,83K,85K\nAN,AN03,AN0195,A,U,20120844515,5/17/1996 0:00,INDU P                           ,MANJULA,PARTHIBAN,1,"| __truncated__,..: 62 147 62 62 24 62 24 147 147 24
 $ URBAN_RURAL: Factor w/ 153 levels ""," ",",01K,31E,61H,81E,83E,85E\nGG,GG01,GG0378,G,R,20120471621,5/19/1996 0:00,KIRAN N,PUSHPA,VISHWANATHA BELCHADA,4,B,K,N,004GG,78,P,"| __truncated__,..: 149 115 149 115 115 115 115 149 149 149
 $ NRC_CLASS  : Factor w/ 117 levels "","01K"," ,01K,31E,61H,81E,83E,85E\nRR,RR01,RR0235,G,R,20120149169,6/25/1995 0:00,BASAVARAJ                        ,NINGAMMA,YANKAPPA,4,"| __truncated__,..: 51 14 51 93 93 93 93 16 51 16
```

`training_data` is something I have constructed from a larger data set by pruning both the rows and columns.

Comment: could you add the output of table(training_data) or str(training_data)

Comment: @ArtemFedosov, Done. table(training_data) was too huge to be printed. I've added str(training_data)

Comment: You probably need to clean your data and/or merge definitions of variables so that there are at most 32 unique values of each.

Comment: @ilir, The columns of training data seem to have 3, 2, 4 unique values respectively. Is the output of str(training_data) contradicting that? It looks like it is showing the values for columns which I pruned away.

Comment: Yep, the number of factor levels is the number of unique values.

Comment: It is possible that the factors retained their levels. Run `x <- factor(x)` for those variables after pruning and check how many unique values they have afterwards.

Comment: @ilir, That worked. Thanks. If you can put that as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are your `factor` variables. They have retained the original levels after pruning (those levels have 0 instances). You can re-convert them to factors, which will drop all unused levels:

```
# define function that reruns factor() for the right columns
rerun_factor <- function(x) {
  if (is.factor(x)) return(factor(x))
  return(x)
}

# run on all columns of your data
training_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(training_data, rerun_factor))
```

One caveat: since this seems to be training data, make sure factor variables have the same levels as test data. You can ensure this by passing an explicit vector of levels: `factor(x, levels=...)`.

Overall, it's a good idea to postpone converting character data to factors until you are done cleaning them. You can pass `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.xxx` function to stop it from being automatically converted.